# Sieve filter that checks if email is a respond to an email of mine

Tags: email, sieve

I have a mail provider which allows me to upload sieve scripts to it. I would like to find out if it's possible to use sieve to make mailing lists subscriptions feel more like web based forums - where I get notifications (emails to my mailbox) just for new messages in *threads* I have replied to / I was mentioned in / I started my self.

To be more specific, the sieve script should check if a given message is part of a thread I have any affiliation with - just as described above.

From reading sieve scripts examples and [the only source of reference I could find](http://sieve.mozdev.org/reference.html), it seems there is no way to get information related to 'threads'. I've wrote an [imapfilter](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter) script that did pretty much what I'd like to do with sieve but even with this tool, it was completely nontrivial to [get a list of all messages](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter/issues/177#issuecomment-485255555) in a thread just by a single message.

Is it even possible to read previously received messages with the sieve standard?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need sieve to deal with more than one message at once, because you only need to identify *one reply* per thread - you can leave dealing with threads to your mail client.

**Your mail client knows how to display only threads with Flagged or Unseen replies.** So mark mailing list content as \Seen or \Flagged using sieve, skipping/filtering on messages that mention Message-ID ending in your domain in headers.

Why can you do that? Because you are typically able to ensure that your **Message-IDs contain something uniquely identifying** your own messages - if that is not already the case (shared domain), the simplest approach would be to modify the domain your mail client uses to generate the Message-ID (e.g. configured as `mail.smtpserver.*.hello_argument` in thunderbird).

- If you store your outgoing mail in a different folder, this approach misses threads where nobody directly replied to you. I suspect those are not the threads you are interested in anyway.
- The advantage of this approach is that your mail client can retroactively assemble threads that only now you are interested in - you will have the entire thread highlighted, even if you replied only somewhere deeper in the reply-to-reply tree.

Comment: Are you sure the `Message-ID` header should contain something that can identify my own messages? I could only see that the domain of that address has the same domain as mine. And what about replies to replies of my messages?

Comment: If it is not yet doing so, you can tell your mail client to chose suitable `Message-ID` headers. How many replies down the thread does not really matter, that "unfold threads with unread/marked messages" feature only needs *one* such message.

Comment: I Use [Neomutt](https://neomutt.org/) and Gmail and it seems it's not possible to automatically set the `Message-ID` with some recognizable information.. Besides that, I'm not sure what do you mean by "unfold threads with unread/marked messages".

Comment: That is the combination of "by default do not show me threads" and "show me threads which contain flagged messages". I assume anything called *mutt understands configuration like `collapse_flagged` and `collapse_all` (flagged or unread depending on what you used to mark your messages in sieve)